# Blender UV unwrapping causes texture to repeat in UDK material

Tags: udk, mesh, materials

I've made pillow kinda thing, unwrapped it in Blender and then I imported my mesh to UDK, applied a material:

[image]

The material splits, but I don't want that to happen, I want to cover the mesh with only big texture, like this one for example:

[image]

How do I do that?

Comment: Unrelated: there are many triangles in that one pillow, you might want to reduce to complexity of the model in Blender with the Decimate modifier.

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be a problem in UDK not in blender:

You need to set `Texture X/Y` to `Wrap` rather than `Clamp`. This is in `Advanced Texture Settings` (click the little eye in the upper right corner of the texture details panel)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I can't understand a single thing I'm not a expert at blender can you simplfy it for me?

Comment: @belkipAndroidness Not in blender. You have to change these settings in UDK. I haven't used UDK but the texture wrap settings should be in `Advanced Texture Settings`.